# Taylor expansion possible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be the hyperbolic tangent. Is $f(|x|)$ a $C^1$ function in the vicinity of $x=0$?
My goal is to linearize this function at $0$, but this might be a problem since the function is not $C^1$ near the origin.

Comment: If we look at the the function under high magnification near $0$, it  is indistinguishable from $|x|$.

Comment: You can probably reach your goal by looking at $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ separately, but do not be afraid to use powers of $|x|$ rather than of $x$. Perhaps that was what @AndréNicolas meant?

Answer (score 1):

No, $f(|x|)$ is not $C^1$ in the vicinity of $x=0$. In fact, it's not even differentiable at $x=0$, and we can see why directly from definitions. Let's define $g(x)=f(|x|)$. Its derivative at $0$ is defined as a limit:

$$g^\prime(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tanh |x|-\tanh|0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tanh |x|}{x}$$

Let's try approaching this limit from above and below:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\tanh |x|}{x}&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\tanh x}{x} = 1\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\tanh |x|}{x}&=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{-\tanh x}{x} = -1
\end{align}$$

Since the one-sided limits are different, the limit $x\to0$ doesn't exist.